# How do i read and write from/to a file in another directory?

Tags: file-io, io, lua, file-read, lua-5.2

I am trying to make a program that will write data to a file for another program to be able to read the data from it. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to do this when the file i am reading and writing from is in another directory than both of my programs. I know there are other ways of doing this, but I just thought that it would be useful to know how to do it. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: `..` in the filename usually means the parent directory. You could use this fact.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Although what if i had a file two or more directories up?

Comment: `../../foo.txt`... have you never *ever* written a single relative file path during your entire life?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the full path, e.g

```
local f1 = io.open('D:/test/b.txt')  -- Windows
local f2 = io.open('/test/b.txt')    -- Unix
```

or use relative path, e.g

```
local f = io.open('../../test/b.txt')
```

In this example, the file is in the `test` directory of the parent directory (`..`) of parent directory.